# Large Database -- More than 1 TB

Tags: database, public

Hi
I am looking for a database of size more than 1 TB that is freely available for performance testing. 
I have already seen a similar thread, but I am not an EC2 user and the other answers that were provided were less than my size requirements. 
Thanks

Comment: If EC2 has what you need, you could become an EC2 user pretty easily.

Comment: What kind of performance testing? And what database are you interested at? An 1TB relational database may behave very different than a column oriented one (NoSQL).

Comment: I am not interested in a database as such. Its the dataset that I want. Sorry if I mislead you

Answer (score 0):

1 terabyte of sample data, compressed, might still be more than 200 gigabytes.

You sure you want to download something like that?

It's pretty easy to write your own sample data generators using text utilities and scripting languages. (And it's a good excuse to learn yet another language, like ruby or python.)

But if you can't do that, you can try searching online. I've found the most useful stuff along these lines by Googling "dataset CDROM" and "dataset DVD".

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. But data generation is not good enough in the project that I am currently working on. I need a real application domain data that might breakdown when a large database is used.

Comment: @Alex: Edited my earlier answer. Google "dataset DVD". I don't know whether there's anything on the scale you're looking for there, though.